# How to find the starting offset of a string slice of another string?

Tags: string, rust

Given a string and a slice referring to some substring, is it possible to find the starting and ending index of the slice?

I have a `ParseString` function which takes in a reference to a string, and tries to parse it according to some grammar:

```
ParseString(inp_string: &str) -> Result<(), &str>
```

If the parsing is fine, the result is just `Ok(())`, but if there's some error, it usually is in some substring, and the error instance is `Err(e)`, where `e` is a slice of that substring.

When given the substring where the error occurs, I want to say something like "Error from characters x to y", where x and y are the starting and ending indices of the erroneous substring.

I don't want to encode the position of the errors directly in `Err`, because I'm nesting these invocations, and the offsets in the nested slice might not correspond to the some slice in the top level string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust actually used to have an unstable method for doing exactly this, but [it was removed due to being obsolete](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/b3aa1a6d4ac88f68e036a05fdf19be63b522b65d), which was a bit odd considering [the replacement didn't remotely have the same functionality](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html).

That said, the implementation isn't that big, so you can just add the following to your code somewhere:

````
pub trait SubsliceOffset {
    /**
    Returns the byte offset of an inner slice relative to an enclosing outer slice.

    Examples

    ```ignore
    let string = "a\nb\nc";
    let lines: Vec<&str> = string.lines().collect();
    assert!(string.subslice_offset_stable(lines[0]) == Some(0)); // &"a"
    assert!(string.subslice_offset_stable(lines[1]) == Some(2)); // &"b"
    assert!(string.subslice_offset_stable(lines[2]) == Some(4)); // &"c"
    assert!(string.subslice_offset_stable("other!") == None);
    ```
    */
    fn subslice_offset_stable(&self, inner: &Self) -> Option<usize>;
}

impl SubsliceOffset for str {
    fn subslice_offset_stable(&self, inner: &str) -> Option<usize> {
        let self_beg = self.as_ptr() as usize;
        let inner = inner.as_ptr() as usize;
        if inner < self_beg || inner > self_beg.wrapping_add(self.len()) {
            None
        } else {
            Some(inner.wrapping_sub(self_beg))
        }
    }
}
````

You can remove the `_stable` suffix if you don't need to support old versions of Rust; it's just there to avoid a name conflict with the now-removed `subslice_offset` method.

Answer (score 8):

As long as all of your string slices borrow from the same string buffer, you can calculate offsets with simple pointer arithmetic. You need the following methods:

- [`str::as_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_ptr): Returns the pointer to the start of the string slice
- A way to get the difference between two pointers. Right now, the easiest way is to just cast both pointers to `usize` (which is always a no-op) and then subtract those. On 1.47.0+, there is a method [`offset_from()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset_from) which is slightly nicer.

Here is working code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4aa7de302fa2d8f8fe80d507677ad586&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
fn get_range(whole_buffer: &str, part: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let start = part.as_ptr() as usize - whole_buffer.as_ptr() as usize;
    let end = start + part.len();
    (start, end)
}

fn main() {
    let input = "Everyone ♥ Ümläuts!";
    
    let part1 = &input[1..7];
    println!("'{}' has offset {:?}", part1, get_range(input, part1));
    
    let part2 = &input[7..16];
    println!("'{}' has offset {:?}", part2, get_range(input, part2));
}
```