# get byte offset after first char of str in rust

Tags: rust

In rust, I want to get the byte offset immediately after of the first character of a `str`.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d0c7e9626492ee33752110d10efc6d4e)

```rust
fn main() {
    let s: &str = "⚀⚁";
    // char is 4 bytes, right??? (not always when in a str)
    let offset: usize = 4;
    let s1: &str = &s[offset..];
    eprintln!("s1 {:?}", s1);
}
```

The program expectedly crashes with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'byte index 4 is not a char boundary; it is inside '⚁' (bytes 3..6) of `⚀⚁`'
```

**How can find the byte offset for the second char `'⚁'` ?**

Bonus if this can be done safely and without `std`.

---

Related:

- [How to get the byte offset between `&str`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38268529/471376)
- [How to find the starting offset of a string slice of another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50781561/471376)

Comment: remember, strings are zero-indexed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` is a 32-bit integer (a unicode scalar value), but individual characters inside a `str` are variable width UTF-8, as small as a single 8-bit byte.

You can iterate through the characters of the `str` and their boundaries using [`str::char_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices), and your code would look like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s: &str = "⚀⚁";
    let (offset, _) = s.char_indices().nth(1).unwrap();
    dbg!(offset); // 3
    let s1: &str = &s[offset..];
    eprintln!("s1 {:?}", s1); // s1 "⚁"
}
```

Comment: Yes, `char_indices` is what I was looking for. Thanks @PitaJ !