Merge 2 slices into a continous slice (bounding box)
Maybe I'm using the wrong words when searching for this, but how do I merge/join/union 2 slices into a slice that covers the 2 given slices and everything in between?
fn main() {
    let text = "the dog and cat run";
    let dog = &text[4..7];
    let cat = &text[12..15];
    let dog_and_cat = &text[4..15]; // <-- how do I 'calculate' this slice?
    println!("{:?}", dog); // "dog"
    println!("{:?}", cat);  // "cat"
    println!("{:?}", dog_and_cat); // "dog and cat"
}

I'm looking for this pseudo-code:
let dog_and_cat = &text[dog.start..cat.end];

or more generally:
let dog_and_cat = &text[min(dog.start, cat.start)..max(dog.end, cat.end)];


You mean std::cmp::min(4, 12)..std::cmp::max(7,15)?

@cafce25: kind of, but without the hardcoded values. I've edit the question to clarify a bit more.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781657.

You've mostly answered your own question, if you have two memory regions, you can neither prove nor disprove that they belong to the same allocation at compile time, because at compile time the allocation does not exist, so you cannot reason about it.
At runtime, as you have already mentioned, you can verify that both memory regions lie within the parent region and merge them. Here's generic enough implementation:
fn main() {
    let string = b"some random text";
    assert!(string.within(&string[5..10]));
    let merged = string.merge(&string[..4], &string[10..]);
    assert_eq!(merged, Some(string.as_ref()));
    let string = "some random text";
    assert!(string.within(&string[5..10]));
    let merged = string.merge(&string[..4], &string[10..]);
    assert_eq!(merged, Some(string.as_ref()));
    let string = "some random text".to_string();
    assert!(string.within(&string[5..10]));
    let merged = string.merge(&string[..4], &string[10..]);
    assert_eq!(merged, Some(string.as_ref()));
}

trait ByteSequence: AsRef<[u8]> {
    fn bounds(&self) -> (*const u8, *const u8) {
        let bytes = self.as_ref();
        let start = bytes.as_ptr();
        let end = unsafe { bytes.as_ptr().add(bytes.len()) };
        (start, end)
    }
    fn merge(&self, seq1: impl ByteSequence, seq2: impl ByteSequence) -> Option<&[u8]>;
    fn within(&self, other: impl ByteSequence) -> bool;
}

impl<T: AsRef<[u8]>> ByteSequence for T {
    fn merge(&self, seq1: impl ByteSequence, seq2: impl ByteSequence) -> Option<&[u8]> {
        (self.within(seq1.as_ref()) && self.within(seq2.as_ref())).then_some(())?;
        let (start1, end1) = seq1.bounds();
        let (start2, end2) = seq2.bounds();
        let (start, end) = (start1.min(start2), end1.max(end2));
        let slice = unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(start, end.offset_from(start) as usize) };
        Some(slice)
    }
    fn within(&self, other: impl ByteSequence) -> bool {
        let (pstart, pend) = self.bounds();
        let (ostart, oend) = other.bounds();

        (pstart..=pend).contains(&ostart) && (pstart..=pend).contains(&oend)
    }
}

Key takeaway is that you can only make assertions about slice properties during runtime, because they are runtime entities. The checks necessary for merge are not that expensive, it's like 8 arithmetic operations for bound checking.

Make the cat's starting point the dog's ending point (whole_dog) to get everything in between using concat():
fn main() {
    let text = "the dog and cat run";
    let dog = &text[4..7];
    let whole_dog = &text[4..12];
    let cat = &text[12..15];
    let dog_and_cat = [whole_dog, cat].concat(); // <--
    println!("{dog}"); // "dog"
    println!("{cat}");  // "cat"
    println!("{dog_and_cat}"); // "dog and cat"
}

… or wrapped in a function:
fn dog_and_cat(text: &str, dog_sp: usize, cat_sp: usize, cat_ep: usize) -> String {
    [&text[dog_sp..cat_sp], &text[cat_sp..cat_ep]].concat()
}

Playground

This code, although working specifically for this sample, might fail for a more general problem. Because the creation of whole_dog is not so clear. Also it generates a new String object instead of &str which might not be what is intended.

@yerlilbilgin If one of the three positions - dog's starting point, cat's starting point, cat's ending point - is unknown, the question would make little sense…

Yes, I agree. That part isn't crystal clear, we are kind of left to notice that, and answer accordingly.

Thank you for your suggestion. You probably noticed that just concat()-ing cat and dog results in a new (copied)  string "catdog", which is not what I want.
About the indices of  slices:  internally in a slice these indices are converted to a pointer to  a  memory block (not owned!) and a length. That's why it's hard to get back these indices. For more info: see my own suggestion.

@ErikBongers I already thought about using the copy_within() function on the dog's slice. This only works with unsafe code, which I don't think is justified given the small timing impact for the copying.

Slices internally
The disadvantage of slices is that they do not contain the indices they were created with. This is for good reason: a slice is effectively (and stored internally as) a pointer to memory and a length. Since slices don't own memory, changing the indices would be unsafe.
Standard solution
The rust team has dabbled with code to change slices, but it's either experimental or deprecated. (see the join_slices() function below)
These solutions either require unsafe code or too stringent restrictions.
So, alas, I have to brew my own.
My current solution.
Contrary to the join_slices() method, that require the 2 slices to be in contiguous memory (which still doesn't guarantee that the 2 slices come from the same memory owner) I decided to implement merge_slices() as a trait on the owner of the memory block, in my case being a str.
This allows me to check (at runtime) if the 2 slices are part of the owner's memory.
Not quite happy
I really would like a solution where I can force the borrow-checker to guarantee that the 2 slices are referencing the same original owner.
I'm not sure if this is even possible, and currently, I'm certainly not proficient enough in rust to implement this.
This is the reason why I hadn't posted my solution so far - the solution below isn't ideal as it should use runtime checks, which I haven't implemented because "trust me I know what I'm doing" and I'm still hoping to find a zero-cost compile time check.
If someone has such a solution, that will be the accepted answer!
Playground
use std::slice;

pub trait MergeSubslices {
    fn merge_slices(&self, slice1: &Self, slice2: &Self) -> &Self;
}

//TODO: check (assert) that the slices are within the memory block of &self.
impl MergeSubslices for str {
    fn merge_slices(&self, slice1: &Self, slice2: &Self) -> &Self {
        let start_self = self.as_ptr() as usize;
        let start1 = slice1.as_ptr() as usize;
        let start2 = slice2.as_ptr() as usize;
        let end1 = start1 + slice1.len();
        let end2 = start2 + slice2.len();
        &self[std::cmp::min(start1, start2)-start_self..std::cmp::max(end1, end2)-start_self]
    }
}

//Taken from https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html
//Not used because slices may be non-contiguous.
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn join_slices<'a, T>(fst: &'a [T], snd: &'a [T]) -> &'a [T] {
    let fst_end = fst.as_ptr().wrapping_add(fst.len());
    let snd_start = snd.as_ptr();
    assert_eq!(fst_end, snd_start, "Slices must be contiguous!");
    unsafe {
        // The assertion above ensures `fst` and `snd` are contiguous, but they might
        // still be contained within _different allocated objects_, in which case
        // creating this slice is undefined behavior.
        slice::from_raw_parts(fst.as_ptr(), fst.len() + snd.len())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let text = "the dog and cat run";
    // let text2 = "the pig and rat run";
    let dog = &text[4..7];
    let cat = &text[12..15];
    let dog_and_cat = &text[4..15]; // <-- how do a get this slice?
    println!("{:?}", dog); // "dog"
    println!("{:?}", cat);  // "cat"
    println!("{:?}", dog_and_cat); // "dog and cat"

    let z = text.merge_slices(dog, cat);
    println!("MERGED: {:?}", z); // "dog and cat"


}

